# I got the same frame from gif

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif

I try to get every frame from a gif, but everytime I get the same one frame.

```py
from PIL import Image
avatar = Image.open("some_gif.gif")
for _ in range(0, avatar.n_frames):
   avatar.seek(avatar.tell() + 1)
   frames.append({"frame": avatar, "duration": avatar.info["duration"]})
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/BigglesZX/4016539 check this out

Comment: I get error illegal image mode